# Vermicompost Consumption Rates

Tags: worms

I'm constantly like a worried mother towards my worm bin, and I know that isn't right because the worms supposedly thrive off of neglect.

I had red wigglers in my bin before I had to get European night-crawlers after a suggestion that they are more hardy. Now, my [360 Worm Factory](https://naturesfootprint.com/worm-factory-360-worm-bin/) is seemingly full of both, so the population doesn't seem too bad.

I had some problems with moisture (way too dry for a long period of time), but recently I've fixed that. My worms have balled up recently and I'm trying to figure out why but I think it's a moisture thing again.

Anyways, my question is this: how long do worms take to eat things? I thought the general rule was every pound of worms can eat 0.5 pounds / day? If that's the case I probably have 200+ worms and they can't finish one fourth of a banana peel within multiple weeks! Could it be because of my environment issues?

Is there a chart I can look at that better describes the rates, or perhaps an online search engine where I can view nearby worm-keepers to maybe get help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A compost worm can eat its own weight in a day if there's suitable food.  Given that they only have tiny mouths without teeth, and they use grit internally along their whole digestive tract to grind things down, then you need to provide food that is already decomposing so they can suck it in. Their other main food sources include fungi from the decomposing matter and bacteria.

So, if your banana skin is not decomposing in the bin, the worms won't be able to eat it.  And if it's not decomposing, it's just too dry inside your bin.